# Position of "further" in "They provide comments for me to further improve my teaching"

Tags: adverbs

I am always confused regarding the position of "further/better" in this kind of structure.

Should it be "They provide comments for me to further improve my teaching" or "They provide comments for me to improve my teaching further?"

Grammarly suggests that I change from the first one to the second one.

Comment: Does *further* actually add something beyond "to improve my teaching"?

Comment: Thanks, Yosef, for your reply. I guess here further here indicates that these comments help me improve in addition to other ways such as self-reflection.

Comment: Grammarly is not a good source of advice.

Comment: @Kevin.J: I don't think "further" particularly implies *improve in addition to **other ways...*** It just means *in addition to your **existing** teaching abilities* - abilities which you might have acquired from *earlier* comments from the same source anyway (it's irrelevant / unspecified *how* you came to have your existing teaching abilities).

Answer (score 2):

Grammarly is likely trying to enforce the supposed rule against split infinitives. In fact, "to further improve" is good enough for the *New York Times*; as just a few examples:

- From [this article:](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/12/21/neediest-cases/pivoting-to-new-horizons-with-career-help.html) "Mr. Johnson saw an opportunity to further improve and distance himself from his past."
- From [this article:](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/05/12/us/politics/biden-cia-brain-injury.html)  "The Biden administration has tried to further improve coordination[...]"
- From [this article:](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/01/01/us/at-veterans-hospital-in-oregon-a-push-for-better-ratings-puts-patients-at-risk-doctors-say.html) "For the few patients who are admitted to Roseburg, other tactics are used to further improve the ratings."

Comment: Thank you! So I guess both work and it's more like personal preference.